# Why does a .NET application prevent Windows from shutting down?

Tags: .net, windows, debugging, shutdown

One of my applications prevents windows from shutting down if it is running.

The only spot where I suspect the cause may be is FormClosing event handler, which is however quite standard:

EDIT: Removing this handler does not change the situation at all so the cause is somewhere else.

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        StopAllThreads(); 
        //let close
        return;
    }
    //ask user whether he wants to save his work
}
```

I have not been able to reproduce this with the simplest possible application containing only this FormClosing handler - the simple application is closed correctly when windows starts shutting down.

What else can prevent windows from shutting down? Where should I look in the code to debug this issue?

I have no custom WndProc implementation in my main form. This is a .NET 2.0 application.

When I run the app in debugger and initiate shutdown, I get only "This program is preventing Windows from shutting down" (Windows 7) for a short while. Windows then shuts down Visual Studio which shuts down the debugger which shuts down the application being debugged.

---

EDIT: StopAllThreads method

```
public static void StopAllThreads()
{
    lock (syncLock)
    {
        foreach (IStop stoppable in stoppables)
        {
            try
            {
                stoppable.Stop(); //stops a running thread by setting a volatile boolean flag
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Fail("Error stopping a stoppable instance: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        stoppables.Clear();
        disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Please note: The application can be closed normally when the user closes it manually.

Comment: What does the code for `StopAllThreads` look like?

Comment: I see that you're using threading (or at least, I assume that you are); could you perhaps have some background threads that aren't getting shut down?

Comment: What happens when you remove this function?

Comment: I see your comment "ask user to save his work". Is there a modal window which appears which prevents the shutdown?

Comment: Have you tried writing some output to the console to see how far the method gets or where the blocking begins? Is the lock to `syncLock` possible or not?

Comment: Seems to me that your threads aren't guaranteed to be stopped by that method. (I.e. it's up to them to get around to checking the flag again, and it may take too long for them to do that, so Windows issues its warning that you haven't responded to the close fast enough).

Comment: @Scoregraphic deadlock at syncLock is not possible. The app prevents shutdown also if I do not try to stop the threads in FormClosing event handler.

Comment: @Scoregraphic: the ask user to save his work does not appear at all unless the form is closed manually. (see the return within closereason check)

Comment: Are those threads started background or foreground threads? Maybe you can set them to foreground threads before closing. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx

Comment: I have tried both values for IsBackground, no change

Comment: As in my second comment...have you done some loggin to see where the application is hanging? Is the problem still the same if you don't run it from inside VS?

Comment: If I run the app outside debugger, nothing happens when I try to shut down Windows (XP) and the app runs normally (is not hung), or the "Application is preventing windows from shutting down" message appears (Windows 7) and if I choose Cancel, the app runs normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved: One of the child forms was overriding `OnClosing`, with the following code:

```
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: And to solve this problem, in my case, I added the condition:

if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        e.Cancel = true;

Answer (score 1):

Have you stepped through this code at all to see whether it gets through executing it all or whether it gets stuck somewhere? Possibly the lock cannot get hold of syncLock for some reason and waits.